# Update element in dataframe based on value in orther column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to know which is the best way to update one element in df based on the value of another coulmn in the same dataframe?

```
p1["price Now"] = df_emptyex["Close"][i]
```

Above is the code I use to update the colum, but every row got the same value under column "price Now".

And the result will be:

| Company | price Now | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ALFA.ST | 192.421814 | 915.41: |
| ASSA-B.ST | 192.421814 | 987.81 |

I want the program to find which row has Company = ASSA-B.ST and update price Now to 200 only on that row like table below:

| Company | price Now | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ALFA.ST | 192.421814 | 915.41: |
| ASSA-B.ST | 200 | 987.81 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `loc`:

```
df.loc[df['Company'] == 'ASSA-B.ST', 'price Now'] = 200
```

```
# Before
>>> df
     Company   price Now    Value
0    ALFA.ST  192.421814  915.41:
1  ASSA-B.ST  192.421814   987.81

# After
>>> df
     Company   price Now    Value
0    ALFA.ST  192.421814  915.41:
1  ASSA-B.ST  200.000000   987.81
```

For more information, you can read the [Selection by label](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-label) section on *Indexing and selecting data* chapter of the user guide.

Comment: Yes you did! Thank you so much :)